# Undefined variable: data

Tags: php, codeigniter

i am still fresher in PHP MVC architecture. here i am trying to list the data in my database table through the model view controller. i am phase this error to fetch the data . i am doing edit my data,. so edit function is not working .

test-table name 
there are few fields to get the data username and email..
please help me to solve this query

here is my Model file.

```
 public function getAllRecords()
        {
            $this->load->library("database");
            $q = $this->db->get("test");
            if($q->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                return $q->result();
            }
            return array();
        }
```

Here is my Controller file

```
 public  function index()
        {
            $this->load->model("testmodel");
            $data['records'] = $this->model->getAllRecords();
            $this->load->view("edit",$data);
        }
```

and it is my View/edit.php file

```
<tr>
                <?php
                if (is_array($data)){

        foreach($data as $row):
   ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?=$row->id?></td>
        <td><?=$row->uname?></td>
        <td><?=$row->email?></td>

     <td> <a href="javascript:edit()">  <img src="../edit.png" alt=""/> </a>  </td>
     <td> <a href="javascript:delete_data()">  <img src="../delete.png" alt=""/> </a>  </td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: use $records instead of $data in your view

Comment: model and controller in same page ?

Comment: no Its both are different page

Comment: I noticed you use `$this->load->library("database");` it should be autoload in `application > config > autoload.php`

Comment: post your updated view page code.

Answer (score 1):

**Controller**

Change

```
$data['records'] = $this->model->getAllRecords();
```

to

```
$data['records'] = $this->testmodel->getAllRecords();
```

**View**

Use `$records` instead of `$data`

Comment: Try to `print_r($records)`. and post the result

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: records in D:\xampp\htdocs\parth\View\edit.php on line 39

Comment: Change your code to what I have posted and print_r($records)

Comment: yes chane the code as per your post but still is not working

Comment: Nothing is change result is same as above can u show my full code of model , view and controller ?.

Comment: What is the result of print_r?

Comment: same is above nothing is change
Notice: Undefined variable: records in D:\xampp\htdocs\parth\View\edit.php on line 39

Answer (score 0):

in your view file use $records instead of $data

```
<?php
    if (is_array($records)){
    foreach($records as $row):
?>
```

when you pass a data from controller to view say

$data['name'] = 'max';
$this->load->view("edit",$data);

in view you can access it with variable $name

Answer (score 0):

**Controller:**

```
public  function index()
    {
        $this->load->model("testmodel");
        $data['records'] = $this->model->getAllRecords();
        $this->load->view("edit",array('data'=>$data));
    }
```

This will work for sure.
Enjoy!